# Spring boot multi module project with common dataSource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring-boot multi module project in which I have different module like controller module , service module and dao module.
I have requirement like I need to define a single point to define data source may be in dao layer or any other separate module just to have database connection.
As it is not possible to have datasource in n number of controller modules (those war file) which may lead to multiple unnecessary connections.
As of now it works only when I define data source in controller module.
Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: What is your problem exactly? You have a multi module spring-boot project and you would like to have a datasource configuration in the dao module instead of the controller one as I understand (correct me if I am wrong), where your controller module is war and dao or service are jars?

Comment: yes right ... i have multiple wars of different controller layer ,but i dont want to have connection there ... I want to have connection in any module but at only one place.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem? You should be able to move ```application.properties``` with data source configuration to any module as long as you provide ```@Configuration``` (```BusinessConfig.class```) in that module and ```@Import``` that  ```@Configuration``` in a different one.

Comment: actually I tried it didnt worked , but still I will try one more time and will update you

Comment: Its not working

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have a multi module `spring-boot` application where there is one war and a set of jars (lets call them library) you can configure it in the following way.

Parent pom (`parent.pom`):

```
<!--group, artifact and so on-->
<modules>
    <module>my-war</module>
    <module>my-library</module>
</modules>
```

war pom: use scope `import`, package `pom`, this way you inherit all dependencies from `spring-boot-dependencies` and technically you can have some kind of many parents.

```
<parent>
    <!--parent group id artifact and version (parent.pom)-->
</parent>
<!--group, artifact and so on-->
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

jar pom our library for example dao:

```
<parent>
    <!--parent group id artifact and version (parent.pom)-->
</parent>

<!--group, artifact and so on-->
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Now in your library module add `application.properties` with your `datasource` connection and configuration class lets call it `BusinessConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"your.package"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"your.package"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"your.package"})
public class BusinessConfig {
}
```

And in your `war` import your `BusinessConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@Import(value = {BusinessConfig.class})
public class Config {
}
```

Comment: For more details check out: https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/#setting-up-the-library-project